# how to decode SD card images and put them into cache/ memory using Fresco?

Tags: android, fresco

I have explored abut Fresco library and concluded that Fresco is eddicient library to fetch images from server, local repository and showcase them.

Any Idea how to decode SD card images and put them into cache/ memory using Fresco?

Comment: Given the available documentation for where Fresco can retrieve images: http://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Local images are already "cached" on the disk, in your case the SD card. You should just load them using one of the supported URIs as outlined by @MorrisonChang or by using `com.facebook.common.util.UriUtil`

Comment: As mentioned above, Fresco take cares of caching images, you just need to set/load images using respective URl.  
You can load SD card Images as: 
mDraweeView.setImageURI(UriUtil.getUriForFile(new File("your file path")));